# Drop shadow for table on rollover?

Tags: css, shadow

I just need to give a dropshadow effect to a table (around its borders) on mouse rollover!

I can do that for DIVs but can't find a way to do it for tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table:hover {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #999;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/JbWmK/2/ for the result.

If that somehow doesn't work, you can always wrap the table in a div and apply the box-shadow to that.

Edit: this obviously won't work in old browsers, but you can use prefixes for that.

Comment: I can't see your result for some reason! does this work on mouse rollover?